# How do I Count if match is found giving error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where I am doing `COUNT` of rows when match is found but it's giving an error:

[image]

It shows the following error:

[image]

I used this formula:

```
=COUNT(I9:AM9,"AP")
```

I tried also this formula which is not working

```
=IFERROR((COUNTIF(I9:AM9,"AP")),"")
```

**if match is not found then should display count zero**

Comment: That is not an error. That is just a note.

Comment: Agreeing with Peh. Just enter "AP" in your range `I9:AM9` and your formula should give 1

Comment: Actually only the second formula is correct, the first one will not work.

Comment: @Peh if it doesnot match then should display count 0

Comment: @tidroyayde yes your example doesn't have an "AP" so it shows `0` correctly.

Comment: what changes when you choose "Update formula to include cells" ?